# routeParams not working properly

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I have basic routing working, but when I try and include params in my routes, nothing renders inside my ngview

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/main.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })

    .when('/second/:num', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/second.html',
        controller: 'mainController'
    })

});

myApp.controller('mainController',
    ['$scope', '$log', '$routeParams', function($scope, $log, $routeParams) {
    $scope.name = "Chris";
    alert($routeParams);
    $scope.num = $routeParams.num;
    $log.info($scope.num)
}]);
```

So when I try and access /second/:num nothing renders in my ngview. But if i do / or /second, those pages work properly

Comment: try this when('/second/:num', {
    templateUrl: '/pages/second.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
  })

Comment: didn't work. im actually not sure whats different here than in my code

Comment: Can you see any error on your browser console?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you please check the controller in second.html page whether the controller is added or not and i suggest always use different controllers for each template.

Best way is use stateProvider easy and flexible than routeProvider both are same but stateProvider is more handy.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('/', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/main.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
  })

  .state('/second/:num', {
    templateUrl: 'pages/second.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
  })

});
myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$log', '$stateParams', function($scope, $log, $stateParams) {
  $scope.name = "Chris";
  alert($stateParams);
  $scope.num = $stateParams.num;
  $log.info($scope.num)
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be something in the way you are declaring the path to your templates, or some kind of error in your console. Below is a repro of your code, with the html files in ng-templates:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider) {

  $routeProvider

  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'main.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
  })

  .when('/second/:num', {
    templateUrl: 'second.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
  })

});
myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$location', '$log', '$route', '$routeParams', function($scope, $location, $log, $route, $routeParams) {
  $scope.name = "Chris";
  $scope.num = $routeParams.num || 'not defined';
  console.log($scope.num);
  
  $scope.goTo = function(number) {
    $location.path('/second/' + number);
  };
  $scope.route = $route.current;
  $scope.goHome = function(number) {
    $location.path('/');
  };
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-route@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="mainController">
    <div ng-view></div>
    
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="main.html">
      <pre>route params: {{route.params}}</pre>
      This is the main page, where $scope.num is {{ num }}
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="num in [0,1,2,3, 'zebra']">
          <button ng-click="goTo(num)">{{ num }}</button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </script>
    
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="second.html">
      <pre>route params: {{route.params}}</pre>
      This is the second page, where $scope.num is {{ num }}
      <br>
      <button ng-click="goHome()">Home</button>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anything jump out at you?